# AWS HTTPS Certification not working more than 48 hours dns update

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns

I bought domain name "deadcomedy.net" via AWS domain registration.
My domain name server is

NS-1.AWSDNS-00.COM

NS-1457.AWSDNS-54.ORG

NS-1675.AWSDNS-17.CO.UK

NS-773.AWSDNS-32.NET

which is recorded on https://whois.net/

also [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHwHr.png)

AWS console shows same NS value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zLtB.png)

Finally I added CNAME tag for certification.
But more than 48 hours after update dns record, AWS certification manager shows "pening" state.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqDpH.png)

I already checked [DNS guide on aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-domain-unavailable.html#troubleshooting-domain-unavailable-transferred-domain-wrong-name-servers) and certification guide also.

Answer (score 1):

It was a DNS zone issue.

To solve this, delete hosting zone and create new one.
then update domain NS value update to new hosting zone's NS value.